# how to solve Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, string

interesting problem: Array to string conversion in
bu there is no string in my code. just only yhere ara 3 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ... ) in on page...

```html
<?php

$sorgu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM genel_google") or die(mysql_error());

$cek = mysql_fetch_array($sorgu);

$title = $cek=['title'];

$aciklama = $cek=['aciklama'];

$anahtar = $cek=['anahtar'];

echo $title;

?>
```

Comment: Could you please reformulate your question and explain what exactly your issue is?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you use to assign variables with db values is wrong, instead try:

```
<?php

    $sorgu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM genel_google") or die(mysql_error());
    $cek = mysql_fetch_array($sorgu);
    $title = $cek['title'];
    $aciklama = $cek['aciklama'];
    $anahtar = $cek['anahtar'];

    echo $title;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = $cek=['title'];
```

`$title` is now `array('title');`, when you echo that, you are converting an array to a string..

you shouldn't place the `=` to access array data:

```
$title = $cek['title'];
$aciklama = $cek['aciklama'];
$anahtar = $cek['anahtar'];
```